# What did I do to cause environment variables to change when I start the Windows command prompt?

Tags: python, windows, command-line, anaconda, environment-variables

I am using Windows 10 x64. I have Anaconda3 installed. If I start C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe with nothing else running (and nothing interesting in the background that I can see), the following is added to the front of my PATH variable that is not present in the Control Panel UI: `C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\condabin\`.

I also see some other environment variables added, which again are not present in the Control Panel UI:

```
CONDA_BAT=C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat
CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
CONDA_SHLVL=0
```

In addition to not showing up in the control panel UI, the environment variables described above do not appear in the output when I run `ls env:` in powershell.

What could be causing this? I think it might be something I set up. I definitely like it, but I don't know what causes it or how to reproduce it. Any ideas?

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963331/windows-environment-variables-change-when-opening-command-line) the answerer explains that this can be caused by launching cmd.exe from some other launcher; however, that's not what I'm doing.

Comment: _something is added_  is unclear. what is added?

Comment: Thanks @buran, good point. I changed "something" to "the following"; does that make sense?

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/ probably you selected to add Anaconda to PATH during installation (not recommended as per the docs - see bullet 8).

Comment: @buran Good idea! I am almost certain that I didn't do that; I remember googling for advice on whether to do so and resolving not to. There's a chance that I later uninstalled and reinstalled and then checked the box, but I don't think I did that. Also, if I had, wouldn't it appear in my environment variables in the Control Panel UI?

Comment: @buran Also, wouldn't checking that box add C:\Users\me\Anaconda3 to my PATH variable, rather than C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\condabin?

Comment: @buran I'm glad you mentioned that; I realized that my post said that C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\conda\bin\conda.bat, but that's wrong; there's no conda.bat. I edited the question.

Comment: **1.** Check [both `AutoRun` registry entries in `HKLM` and `HKCU`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433) e.g. `reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor"`. **2.** Check _user path_ `reg query HKCU\Environment /v Path` as well as  _system path_ `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path`

Comment: Thanks a lot @JosefZ! I think that's exactly it. I think your answer is equivalent to the one I just posted from reddit user 4wh457. I will delete my answer so you can get the credit.

Comment: I think reddit user 4wh457 solved my problem in an equivalent way to SO user @JosefZ. It turns out that I created a registry key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor with the following properties (in the RegCool interface):

NAME = AutoRun

Type = REG_EXPAND_SZ

Data = if exist "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat" "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat"

Comment: @capet thanks; please undelete your answer;  it's more precise than my guessing so it can help others with the same issue…

Comment: Okay, fair enough!

Answer (score 1):

Reddit user [4wh457](https://www.reddit.com/user/4wh457) and SO user [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) solved my problem. It turns out that I created a registry key in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor with the following properties (in the RegCool interface):

- NAME = AutoRun
- Type = REG_EXPAND_SZ
- Data = if exist "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat" "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat"

Per [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz), the AutoRun key could have also been here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

(further documentation [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433)).