# Anaconda: How do I tell whether I checked the box for "Add Anaconda3 to my PATH environment variable"?

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, environment-variables

(h/t to [Buran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran) for leading me to ask this question)

I'm using Windows 10 x64. I installed Anaconda3 a while ago. When I installed it, I had the option to check a box labeled "Add Anaconda3 to my PATH environment variable"? I'm pretty sure that I did not, because I remember googling and finding that I shouldn't.

This is also discussed on the Anaconda website, thank you to [Buran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4046632/buran): https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/.

But I might have checked the box. Is there a way to figure out whether I checked the box?

I thought that the right way to check was to look at my environment variables using the Control Panel UI, i.e. the thing shown below (and clicking the "Environment Variables..." button):

[image: System Properties -> Advanced]

(the question that led to this question: [What did I do to cause environment variables to change when I start the Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095439/what-did-i-do-to-cause-environment-variables-to-change-when-i-start-the-windows))

Answer (score 3):

In environment variables, you will find your env vars for the user and the system, in both you should have a PATH variable, check if inside them there is a link to the anaconda script.

Comment: Thanks a lot @frab! There are none. If I look at my environment variables using the control panel UI shown above, then in both system and user environment variables (including PATH), the strings "conda", "CONDA", "python", "PYTHON" do not appear in any variable. Does that suggest that I did not check the box?

Comment: I get the same result as above using Powershell ls env:

Comment: However, I get a different result if I open C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe and run set. If I do that, C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\conda appears at the front of my PATH variable (which it does NOT if I use powershell or the Control Panel), and I also get three new environment variables that didn't appear in the above two methods (control panel and Powershell): CONDA_BAT, CONDA_EXE, CONDA_SHLVL. This seems to happen even when I have nothing beyond normal Windows stuff running in the background, and no other applications open. Weird? I think I might have caused this with some other setting, not sure.

Comment: I will mark this as the answer on Friday, just to give the question time to breathe. Thanks again @frab!!!

Comment: then those variables are environment variables, but the variable PATH doesn't contain the anaconda script. Those are different environmentvariables (like PATH)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that probably means I didn't check the box, right? Just to be clear, those strings (conda, python) do not appear in any environment variable (variable name or variable value) at all using the control panel UI or powershell.

Comment: Exactly, you didn't check the box. As an additional check, you could write "conda activate" in cmd. It should raise an error.

Comment: I'm glad you said that! What's weird is that it does NOT raise an error--that's actually why I asked this question. When I run C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe and run set (just after reboot, with nothing interesting running in the background and no open applications, I swear), my environment variable setup is revealed to be different than what is described in the Control Panel UI and also in PowerShell. I have three new variables CONDA_BAT, CONDA_EXE, CONDA_SHLVL, and C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\conda appears at the front of my PATH variable. Any clue why?

Comment: Also, those three "CONDA" variables plus the conda-related prefix to my PATH variable do NOT appear if I look at the following registry keys: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment; HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment

Comment: Yes it does--I have no clue why! (Presumably it is those environment variables but I don't know where they come from.) I feel like I might have done something special to make that happen, but I don't remember.

Comment: those variables are created when you activate the conda environment. if there is not link to the anaconda script in PATH variables you shouldn't be able to activate anything. the presence of those variables means that the anaconda script has been called

Comment: that makes sense, but what's weird is that those variables are there before I run "conda activate", right after starting up a fresh command prompt.

Comment: When I start the command prompt, I don't think the environment is activated because it does not say "(base)" in front of my working directory. Right after opening the prompt, without it saying base, set returns those "extra" environment variables. Then I can call conda activate, and then "(base)" appears in front of my working directory. But the "extra" environment variables appear even before I activate. Does that make sense?

Comment: try digiting "where conda" in a fresh cmd

Comment: C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, Navigate through Control Panel->Advanced system settings->Advanced Tab->Environment Variables
There will be 'User variables' and 'System variable', we generally use User variable.
Under 'User variables' select "Path" and click on Edit, Here you will find the list of Paths ordered based on priority of programs for easy access from any directory.
You can edit as per your preference.